# Weird error from Nagios on Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: ubuntu, nagios

I have nagios 3 running on Ubuntu 10.4 and I get a weird email sometimes.

> ** PROBLEM Host Alert: localhost is DOWN **
>
> ***** Nagios *****
>
> Notification Type: PROBLEM Host:
>   localhost State: DOWN Address:
>   127.0.0.1 Info: (Return code of 127 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing)
>
> Date/Time: Thu Aug 19 15:00:43 EDT
>   2010

Today it happened at 9:00, 11:00, 13:00 and 15:00 exactly. So there must be something running at these times to cause it, but there's nothing weird in the root crontab and nothing at all in the nagios crontab. Additionally there's no error showing in the nagios website. Anyone see this before?

here's my localhost.cfg: http://friendpaste.com/6bkUfWfGVI93Z5caJo6uGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it's saying it can't find the `check_ping` command (which is used to determine if the host is up or not). You're configuration is probably set to alert you every 2 hours, hence the timing.

What location does your `checkcommands.cfg` say the `check_ping` plugin is located? Check to see if it's there? Also, if you have a 64-bit machine, Nagios may be trying to look for the plugins under /usr/lib/nagios/plugins when it should be /usr/**lib64**/nagios/plugins

Comment: I don't think that's it. I get alerts right when they error out and there are *no* errors in the web interface. That also means the plugins should be fine. Also, I'm running 32bit.

Comment: Also there's no ping service for localhost

Comment: What if you run the commands by hand? There should be a `check-host-alive` command defined somewhere. It usually looks like `$USER1$/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 1` where `$USER1$` is your plugins dir. Is this constantly going on, or just sporadically?